# Implementing an onItemClickListener for card view items in android

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

Hi I cannot figure out how to listen to a click event on a card item using the onItemClickListener. A card item is any view inside a card view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across a similar requirement, I was able to solve the issue using the following.

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titleTextView;
    public ImageView coverImageView;
    public ImageView likeImageView;
    public ImageView shareImageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        coverImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.coverImageView);
        likeImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.likeImageView);
        shareImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.shareImageView);
        likeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                int id = (int)likeImageView.getTag();
                    if( id == R.drawable.ic_like){

                        likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                        likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),titleTextView.getText()+" added to favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{

                        likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_like);
                        likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),titleTextView.getText()+" removed from favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
            }
        });

        shareImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                        "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(coverImageView.getId())
                        + '/' + "drawable" + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName((int)coverImageView.getTag()));

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

source : http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/android-cardview-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks man. I actually don't know why I muted this thread. Well better late 2years than never.